# spacing issue on css drop down menu, cannot center text and cannot get rid of excess left side space

Tags: html, css, menu, spacing

Okay, so I created a drop down menu.

Before I added the `ul` and `li` tags, it centered fine.  Now it won't center.  I tried adding left/right as auto, text-align center and even going into the div tag itself and putting align center, nothing works.  So I added extra space to some of the menu items, but overall nothing looks properly spaced.

My second issue is that on the drop downs, there appears to be some extra left side spacing and I cannot figure out why it is there or how to get rid of it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="menu" align="center">
    <ul>
        <!-- main ul tag -->
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <!-- close home li tag -->
        <li class="aboute"><a href="#">About Ebenezer</a>

            <ul>
                <!-- About Ebenezer menu -->
                <li class="aboute"><a href="#">Our History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="aboute"><a href="#">Our Pastor</a>
                </li>
                <li class="aboute"><a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- close About Ebenezer menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- close About Ebenezer li tag -->
        <li class="min"><a href="#">Ministries</a>

            <ul>
                <!-- Ministries menu -->
                <li><a href="#">Women</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Men</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Youth</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- close Ministries menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- close Ministries li tag -->
        <li class="min"><a href="#">Community</a>

            <ul>
                <!-- Community menu -->
                <li><a href="#">Backpack Buddies</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Outreach</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- close Community menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- close Community li tag -->
        <li class="min"><a href="#">Events</a>

            <ul>
                <!-- Events menu -->
                <li><a href="#">Calendar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- close Events menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- close Events li tag -->
        <li class="photos"><a href="#">Photos</a>

        </li>
        <!-- close Photos li tag -->
        <li class="non-list"><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
        <!-- close Contact li tag -->
    </ul>
    <!-- end of main ul tag -->
</div>
<!-- end of menu -->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#menu {
    height: 40px;
    width: 1104px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: choco;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#menu ul li.non-list {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100px;
}
#menu ul li.aboute {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 195px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 15px;
}
#menu ul li.min {
    left: 15px;
}
#menu ul li.photos {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 160px;
}
#menu ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
#menu ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: #f3b830;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #f3b830;
}
```

Comment: "it centered fine" it is the menu itself..? or the items..?

Comment: Both, if I adjust the spacing for the menu items to a smaller number, home gets closer to the left.  And there's some weird extra spacing on the left on the drop downs.

Comment: looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3d8cA/3/embedded/result/)?

Comment: Yes!  That looks a like what I'm trying to get.

Comment: So, if I make the font smaller, I have an issue with spacing between words on the menu.  Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the spacing issue between menu items by specifying a height for the `<li>` and pulling the submenus down by applying `top` equal to the height set for `<li>`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3d8cA/5/)

*It's better to avoid tags and properties such as `align` for styling purpose and do the styling using css*

Answer (score 0):

```
try it mate, i think its fine now, Im set a width as auto or 100%, remove some margin, left, and add small padding .. 

    <html><head><style>
#menu {
    height: 40px;
    width: 1104px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: choco;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#menu ul li.non-list {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100px;
}
#menu ul li.aboute {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: auto;
    /* margin-left: -10px; */
    padding: 0px;
    /* left: 15px; */
}
#menu ul li.min {
    left: 15px;
}
#menu ul li.photos {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0c495c;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 160px;
}
#menu ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
#menu ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
}
#menu ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: #f3b830;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #f3b830;
}
</style>

</head><body><div id="menu" align="center">
    <ul>
        <!-- main ul tag -->
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <!-- close home li tag -->
        <li class="aboute"><a href="#">About Ebenezer</a>

            <ul>
                <!-- About Ebenezer menu -->
                <li class="aboute" style="
    /* display: block; */
    /* width: 100%; */
"><a href="#">Our History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="aboute"><a href="#">Our Pastor</a>
                </li>
                <li class="aboute"><a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- close About Ebenezer menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- close About Ebenezer li tag -->
        <li class="min"><a href="#">Ministries</a>

            <ul>
                <!-- Ministries menu -->
                <li><a href="#">Women</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Men</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Youth</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- close Ministries menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- close Ministries li tag -->
        <li class="min"><a href="#">Community</a>

            <ul>
                <!-- Community menu -->
                <li><a href="#">Backpack Buddies</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Outreach</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- close Community menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- close Community li tag -->
        <li class="min"><a href="#">Events</a>

            <ul>
                <!-- Events menu -->
                <li><a href="#">Calendar</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- close Events menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- close Events li tag -->
        <li class="photos"><a href="#">Photos</a>

        </li>
        <!-- close Photos li tag -->
        <li class="non-list"><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
        <!-- close Contact li tag -->
    </ul>
    <!-- end of main ul tag -->
</div>
<!-- end of menu --></body></html>
```